# Existence of a smooth path connecting two points

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Let $U=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 | 1<x^2+y^2<4\}$. Let $p,q\in U$. Show that there is a continuous map $\gamma : [0,1] \to U$ such that $\gamma (1)=q$ and $\gamma (0)=p$ and such that $\gamma$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$

---

I really don't know how think this problem $\gamma $ is a continuous function and given that $\gamma (1)=q$  and $\gamma (0)=p$ then how construct $\gamma $ is differentiable on $(0,1)$? Any help plzzz..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Identify $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the complex plane $\mathbb{C}.$ Write $p=r_1 e^{i\theta_1}$ and $q=r_2 e^{i\theta_2}$.

Consider

$$\gamma(t)=(tr_1+(1-t)r_2)e^{i(t\theta_1+(1-\theta_2)}.$$

Comment: Damn, same solution simultaneously.  I'm deleting mine :D.  +1.

Comment: I don't see why. It is correct. It was just a coincidende to write them at the same time.

Comment: There are some people who would downvote answers that are the same.  I somewhat agree that there is no need to have two virtually identical answers (but I don't downvote them because two people can have the same idea).

Comment: I would vote your answer +1 as it is as good as mine (or better, or worse. There is no difference.) I don't worry about upvotes or downvotes.

Comment: No worries.  At least this thread has good answers now.  That's more important than having my answer here.

Comment: i understand but then what is the importance of that $U=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 | 1<x^2+y^2<4\}$

Comment: That it is path connected. That is, you can join two points of $U$ along a path. Indeed, in a differentiable way.

Answer (score 1):

Write $p=(a\cos(\alpha),a\sin(\alpha))$ and $q=(b\cos(\beta),b\sin(\beta))$ with $1<a,b<2$.
Then define
\begin{align}
&r(t)=a(1-t)+bt&
&\theta(t)=\alpha(1-t)+\beta t
\end{align}
$$\gamma(t)=(r(t)\cos(\theta(t)),r(t)\sin(\theta(t)))$$